# `unquote` and `binding_quote` in case expression

Tags: metaprogramming, elixir

This works:

```
defmacro returning(expr, do: block) do
  quote do
    case unquote(expr), do: unquote(block)
  end
end
```

But this doesn't:

```
defmacro returning(expr, do: block) do
  quote bind_quoted: [expr: expr, block: block] do
    case expr, do: block
  end
end
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's about context. The following code is equivalent to the one that uses `bind_quoted`:

```
defmacro returning(expr, do: block) do
  quote do
    expr = unquote(expr)
    block = unquote(block)
    case expr, do: block
  end
end
```

So let's say we write something like:

```
returning(true) do
  true -> :ok
  false -> :not_ok
end
```

This generates the following AST:

```
{:__block__, [],
 [{:=, [], [{:expr, [], Test}, true]},
  {:=, [], [{:block, [], Test}, [{:->, [line: 46], [[true], :ok]}, {:->, [line: 47], [[false], :not_ok]}]]},
  {:case, [], [{:expr, [], Test}, [do: {:block, [], Test}]]}]}
```

This tuples work as follows:

```
{<name of the function>, <context>, <arguments>}
```

- In the second line you see `{:=, [], [{:expr, [], Test}, true]}` which is equivalent to `expr = true`. This won't raise any error.
- In the third line is a bit more complex. The first part is a variable binding `block = <something>`. `<something>` in this context, Elixir interprets the `true -> :ok` and `false -> :not_ok` clauses as the functions `->([true], :ok)` and `->([false], :not_ok)`, tries to evaluate them and doesn't find them.

The other macro, the one that doesn't fail, you would get for the same code the following AST:

```
{:case, [],
 [true,
  [do: [{:->, [line: 42], [[true], :ok]},
        {:->, [line: 43], [[false], :not_ok]}]]]}
```

In the context of a case, the `:->` is interpreted as clauses of a `case` statement and not functions. There is no binding of variables prior the `case` declaration, so for the compiler everything is find.

And that's the reason `bind_quoted` doesn't work in this case. Simply because is not aware of the context.

I hope this answers your question.

*PS*:

I used the following code to check the differences in the AST of the macros:

```
defmodule Test do
  defmacro good_returning(expr, do: block) do
    ast = quote do
      case unquote(expr), do: unquote(block)
    end
    IO.inspect ast
    :ok
  end

  defmacro bad_returning(expr, do: block) do
    ast = quote bind_quoted: [expr: expr, block: block] do
      case expr, do: block
    end
    IO.inspect ast
    :ok
  end
end

import Test
good_returning(true) do
  true -> :ok
  false -> :not_ok
end

bad_returning(true) do
  true -> :ok
  false -> :not_ok
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write up this wonderful explanation. Much appreciated! Having the test code to go along is _very_ helpful too. Kudos!